# Tried installing mysql using brew, cmake builds fails error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, homebrew, rbenv, linuxbrew

I'm installing mysql using brew on Linux (Ubuntu 14.04)

I type this `brew install mysql`  command I get the following errors

```
==> Installing mysql dependency: cmake
==> Downloading http://www.cmake.org/files/v3.2/cmake-3.2.2.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /home/sharif/.cache/Homebrew/cmake-3.2.2.tar.gz
==> Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/S/Sphinx/Sphinx-1.2.3.ta
Already downloaded: /home/sharif/.cache/Homebrew/cmake--sphinx-1.2.3.tar.gz
==> python -c import setuptools... --no-user-cfg install --prefix=/tmp/cmake2015
--record=installed.txt

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named setuptools

READ THIS: https://github.com/Homebrew/linuxbrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/Troubleshooting.md#troubleshooting

These open issues may also help:
cmake builds fail on CLT-only with --env=std (https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/29101)
```

Its is stuck on this tried many a times, don't know what should I do. I'm a naive first time ever installing installing ruby on rails with mysql. I'm following a tutorial which show how to install ruby on rails on MAC I'm copying the same command but got error on this point ..

Please note that I've installed linusbrew, any help would be highly appreciated.

any idea?

Comment: Is there a reason you're trying to install with homebrew, or do you just want mysql installed? It looks like [using `apt-get`](https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/mysql.html) might be easier.

Comment: thanks for your comment @AndrewPiliser nothing really had issues previously when I installed using `apg-get` could not install mysql2 gem, now find this turorial the person in the video is using the same method and successfully installed, ruby on rails with mysql and mysql2 gem

Comment: you need the mysql dev package for the gem to install successfully `sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev`